# assigning value-dependent colour gradients to bar plot in R base

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

Given a set of values:

```
x<-sort(100*round(runif(10, 0.0, 1.0), digits=2))
```

The rainbow() palette can be used to assign colours to each bar of a bar plot as a function of the total number of bars:

```
barplot(x,col=rainbow(length(x)))
```

[image: example]

Is there a simple solution to assign colours from the rainbow palette as a function of the values represented by each bar, so that closer values would have more similar colours?

Comment: You could create a palette function using `palFun <- colorRampPalette(rainbow(length(x)))` and then `barplot(x,col=palFun(max(x))[x])` or `barplot(x,col=palFun(diff(range(x))+1)[x-min(x)+1])`.

Comment: Thank you for thinking of something that works even when the vector contains negative values. If you post this as an answer I can check it as the accepted solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you could do

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(100*round(runif(10, 0.0, 1.0), digits=2))

palFun <- colorRampPalette(rainbow(length(x))) 
barplot(x,col=palFun(diff(range(x))+1)[x-min(x)+1], names.arg = x)
```

[image]